# HOW can I have a SSRS parameter display or not display based on a prior parameter (dynamically)?

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, parameters

My report has a Parameter with 5 choices.  I was thinking that, if a specific choice was made, that another Parameter would prompt the user to answer an additional question/setting.   Can this be done in SSRS 2008?  If not, I will just hard code 1 way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can.  You basically bind a dataset with a predicate to the first variable.

UPDATED

1. Say I declare parameter 'choices'.
2. I create a dataset also called Choices that is just a simple two row return:

   ```
   Select 'ChoiceA' as Choice
   union
   Select 'ChoiceB'
   ```
3. I go back to parameter in step 1 and choose on the left pane 'Available Values' and say 'Get values from a query' choose the dataset I called 'Choices' and then choose 'Choice' as the value and the label.  Now when you preview the report the parameter has a drop down with two choices.  But you wanted to know if it could affect more, it can.
4. Add another dataset called 'SubChoices' and make it's dataset be:

   ```
    Select * 
    from (
     Select 'ChoiceA' as Choice, 'Yes' as SubChoice
     Union
     Select 'ChoiceA', 'No'
     Union
     Select 'ChoiceB', NULL
   ) as x 
   where Choice = @Choices
   order by SubChoice desc
   ```

   Notice I am declaring a dataset yet referencing a variable I had done above.  I just created a dependency on this dataset for the first one.  UPDATE: I added an order by clause and changed the inside nested select to be more tailored to your specific case.
5. Now create a parameter called 'SubChoices' and make it's 'Available Values' from 'Get values from a query' and use 'SubChoices' as the dataset and the subchoice as the value and label.  UPDATE: Ensure you set it to 'Allow null value' under general.  This time set the 'Default Values' to ALSO be the query and Subchoice.  What this will do is take the FIRST ONE it gets and pop that one in as the default.  Since you only want choices for certain first choices if I do not want values for ChoiceB I set a 'NULL' in the dataset meaning nothing.  So if a user choices ChoiceA they get two options and YES should default, if they choose Choice B they get a null, meaning nothing.
6. Now test the report, you should havea first parameter with a drop down for two values, 'ChoiceA' or 'ChoiceB'.  You have another parameter next to it grayed out.  Once you fill out the first one, the second one will display values that only display values associated from the first.  Due to the fact of my having a where clause the second parameter is DEPENDENT on the first and thus will not be able to be used till the first one is done and also will only display the values related to the first value.

HTH, dependent values are a powerful part of SSRS.

Comment: AWESOME.  Thanks much for the help--and the very detailed description.

Comment: follow up question....If I already have the 1st parameter (@ReportOrder) with the 5 choices and I only want the 2nd parameter (SubChoice) to activate when @ReportOrder = 0, I am drawing a blank as to what I do to the query for the SubChoice dataset.  I only need 2 choices.  I want the 2nd parameter to prompt the user with something to the effective of "Replicate balance and aging among each Analyst (Y/N)?" and then them only having a Yes or No answer option.

Comment: You would just make a dataset that gets those two choices like 'Select  * From( Select (whateveryoursubis) as SubValue, 0 as Link as FORCEDJOIN UNION Select (whateveryoursubis), 0) as x where Link = @Param1'.   You are making a relationship exist in this case where there is none.  But you need to add to this variable to accept 'NULL' in the general screen now as you don't want this populated it sounds like EXCEPT when a certain instance arises.

Comment: Ohh and welcome to stack overflow, if you feel you got a correct answer mark this one complete or else I can further update the example for more thorough examples

Comment: I either don't follow that last statement or there is a typo.  My 2 subchoices are YES and NO.  I want it to default to NO--but should be able to set that using the DEFAULT VALUES option in the Parameter properties.

Comment: If I mark this as complete, will I be precluded from asking these follow-up questions?  Sorry to sound like a NOOB or idiot.  I have no idea how to mark this question as Complete, either.

Comment: No that won't happen, but I updated my answer so you can look at it more regardless.

Comment: Ok, so I'm thinking that I do not need your dataset (or parameter) for Choices--using only Subchoices.  Since I already have a parameter setup, I only need the subchoices for it.  I follow your example but just can't translate it to my instance without using the interim parameter (which seems to be overkill).

Comment: I thought I figured it out and altered your qry as follows.  I have 5 choices (0-4).  But, when the 1st param = 0, this works, but when it is anything else, the 2nd param appears (no longer grayed out) but there are no choices.  Select * 
 from (
  Select 0 as Choice, 'No' as SubChoice
  Union
  Select 0 , 'Yes'
  Union
  Select 1, NULL
  Union
  Select 2, NULL
  Union
  Select 3, NULL
  Union
  Select 4, NULL
) as x 
where Choice = @ReportOrder
order by SubChoice desc

Comment: It should show a (Null) in the box if you selected to have the 'default' be from a query as well and if you also allowed to have nulls.

Comment: If anything other than 0 is selected in the 1st Parameter, the 2nd Parameter shows <Select a Value> but there are no choices to select.  I thought that 2nd parameter would be grayed out in all instances except when 0 is chosen in the 1st parameter (BTW, when 0 is selected first, it works properly).

Comment: You need to ensure that you ALSO set the default values to ALSO be get values from a query.

Comment: Definitely did that.  I am not able to chat.  Do you want to communicate outside of this forum or just continue?  Basically, you gave me what I needed.  Its just that I can't make that 2nd Parameter appear when needed. It populates with choices when needed but is there all the time.  So, I will probably do away with it because users will get frustrated that they are prompted to select something but are not able to do so.  Even the question for the parameter (prompt) always exists.

Comment: 2nd Parameter should always appear, it is either populated with Yes or No for choice 0 or else it auto populates with (null) if anything else.  Need to ensure that you set the parameter to have 'Allow null' in the general section or else it will not work.

Comment: In your original instructions (step 6), the 2nd parameter is grayed out.  I want it to remain that way--to only appear--when 0 is selected in the first prompt.  That goes back to my original question.  I only want the 2nd parameter to exist under certain conditions.  In this case, 1 condition (when the answer to parameter 1 is 0).

Comment: You can't do that with SSRS as far as I know, it is grayed out initially but then populates with values.  As far as I know you can't have it only display for certain criteria but otherwise be invisible.  It either is hidden and never displays or else always displays and you limit scope.  You could set it to null but then a user would never be prompted to change the values.  You can do some simple dependencies with SSRS but not advanced event driven flows controlling displays to be shown or not shown on the parameters.